# PHP Variable from echo variable of sql table

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a PHP files where inside i've got this line:

```
source: "<?php echo $this->row->cdkey;?>"
```

that returns a number like 124982149

I need to pass this into a php variable

But if i try:

```
$variable = '<?php echo $this->row->cdkey;?>';
```

it doesn't retun anything.

How can i solve this without connecting to mysql?

Comment: what about `$variable =  $this->row->cdkey;` ?

Comment: Try `$variable = $this->row->cdkey`

Comment: Answered About This,

Comment: They doubled Qs rep and now we have such a question that got an upvote. OP will reach privileges much faster without being enogh prepared and educated about SO. This is the true outcome.

Comment: no one of this working. it seems that i can get the content of the row cdkey only with the code <?php echo $this->row->cdkey;?>    but i need to pass it into a variable... any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

if you can change code in php file like below

```
return $this->row->cdkey;
```

Call it where you want

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($filePath);
$variable =  eval($fileContent);
```

if you can not change code in php file 
than you just use CURL [link](https://codular.com/curl-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `php` to save this to a variable, like this.

```
$variable = $this->row->cdkey;
```

There is *no need* to **open** and **close** `php` tag inside another php tag, Then simply echo or print `$variable` anywhere to get `$this->row->cdkey`.